# Java Session in Jboss Cluster

Tags: java, jboss, spring-security, httpsession

Our application was working fine in SIT enviornment(not in cluster) . Now we moved it to UAT enviormmnt which is in JBoss cluster(2 nodes one cluster).

Now a strange problem.

3 war files were deployed:

1. Admin application
2. EHS app
3. Visa app (ours)

Successful Login directs to admin application. 
There we have 2 links ; one to Visa app and one to EHS app.

Problem is...
When we click on or application link(Visa app), navigation is not happening. [Spring security information is not available from httpsession] 
But if we click on EHS link and return back to Home page and then click on our link (Visa app) ; it navigates.

Log says httpsession object is null.
But all these  apps were working in SIT environment.
So confused..

Other 2 application has    ‘authentication method as ‘FORM” in web.xml

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>TKSOnlineServicesRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsp?error=1</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

But our application has  ‘BASIC’ .

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>TKSOnlineServicesRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Could this be the issue.
Unable to track. Please help. It is urgent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure your JBoss servers to do **session replication** and/or **sticky sessions**. If not, user session is only stored in one of JBoss servers and the other one doesn't know about this user, avoiding him to navigate in your application.

There are plenty of information about configuring this, but I would recommend to check [this](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/jboss_admin_tutorial/high_availability_and_scalability.html) link to accomplish that, may help you to configure all JBoss clustering stuff.

Comment: This link was very useful. But session replication is configured by adding the 'distributable/> tag in web.xml and the load balancer is configured for sticky session I believe (To this cluster enviornmnent, we dont have access). If the load balancer dont have sticky session; will it help? Also will REPL_ASYNC help?

Comment: `<distributable/>` in your `web.xml` is ok. But, you have a `jboss-web.xml` in your app to config clustering there? I'd recomment to use sticky sessions but, it should work without it too. Secondly, remember to start JBoss with `-all` (or custom profile with clustering modules) configuration to enable clustering in both instances.

Comment: `REPL_ASYNC` is the default JBoss cache mode, should work this way.

Comment: this was finally useful to you?